# PHP content not showing

Tags: php, html, css

I have some HTML content on a PHP echo command in a separate php file. The code is shown below..

```
  <?php
echo "
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer-contact">
                <p><strong>Gardencrafts Heswall Limited</strong> <br> The Nurseries, Lower Thingwall Lane, Thingwall, <br> Wirral CH61 1AZ</p>
                <p><strong>Telephone :</strong> 0151 648 5840</p>
                <p><strong>Fax :</strong> 0151 648 5840</p>
                <p><strong>Email :</strong> gardencrafts1@gmail.com</p>
         </div>
         <div id="footer-icons">
            <div id="social-tab">
                <div id="twitter"><a href='https://twitter.com/GardencraftsUk' class='twitter-follow-button' data-show-count="false">Follow @GardencraftsUk</a></div>
                <div class="fb-like" data-href='https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gardencrafts/200615766704712?fref=ts' data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="awards">
                    <img src="images/f1.jpg">
                    <img src="images/f2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/f3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="copy">
               <p>Copyright © 2011 Gardencrafts.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
";
 ?>
```

I included this in a php page with the following code.

```
 <?php include("../script/footer.php"); ?>
```

The scrpit is in a folder called scrpit in the web site root.. but when I include this, the content is not showing! Can any one please help me!

Thank you.

Comment: have you got any error ? may be your path problem.

Comment: Your content is not properly enclosed with quota, if you used "content" the you need escape all " with \" and when using 'content' you escape ' with \' example: $var = 'Isn't'; must be 'Isn\'t';

Comment: I noticed the down-vot. Aren't you becoming to harsh lately? He's at the beginning, at the stupid questions phase, give them a brake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your file. Add `\` to escape the quotes or change them to single ones:

```
 <?php
echo "
    <div id=\"footer\">
        <div id=\"footer-contact\">
                <p><strong>Gardencrafts Heswall Limited</strong> <br> The Nurseries, Lower Thingwall Lane, Thingwall, <br> Wirral CH61 1AZ</p>
                <p><strong>Telephone :</strong> 0151 648 5840</p>
                <p><strong>Fax :</strong> 0151 648 5840</p>
                <p><strong>Email :</strong> gardencrafts1@gmail.com</p>
         </div>
         <div id=\"footer-icons\">
            <div id=\"social-tab\">
                <div id=\"twitter\"><a href='https://twitter.com/GardencraftsUk' class='twitter-follow-button' data-show-count=\"false\">Follow @GardencraftsUk</a></div>
                <div class=\"fb-like\" data-href='https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gardencrafts/200615766704712?fref=ts' data-send=\"false\" data-layout=\"button_count\" data-width=\"200\" data-show-faces=\"false\" data-font=\"trebuchet ms\"></div>
            </div>
            <div id=\"awards\">
                    <img src=\"images/f1.jpg\">
                    <img src=\"images/f2.jpg\">
                    <img src=\"images/f3.jpg\">
            </div>
            <div id=\"copy\">
               <p>Copyright © 2011 Gardencrafts.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
";
 ?>
```

Comment: But this is an actual answer to the actual question, why would it suit better as a comment and not as an answer?

Comment: The footer is static here! so if I try copy pasting for the entire pages, I'll die! :P so instead I use a single php script and echo it where I need! :)

Comment: Yup I understood that you can just write html in your php page, no need to echo.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you echo such a HTML block ? There's no need to do that.
Is your path right ? (What you describe would be include('script/footer.php');)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php include("script/footer.php"); ?>
```

include you footer file like this. think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First after echo and at the end use single quotes instead of double quotes and it will work, like so:

```
    <?php
echo '
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer-contact">
                <p><strong>Gardencrafts Heswall Limited</strong> <br> The Nurseries, Lower Thingwall Lane, Thingwall, <br> Wirral CH61 1AZ</p>
                <p><strong>Telephone :</strong> 0151 648 5840</p>
                <p><strong>Fax :</strong> 0151 648 5840</p>
                <p><strong>Email :</strong> gardencrafts1@gmail.com</p>
         </div>
         <div id="footer-icons">
            <div id="social-tab">
                <div id="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/GardencraftsUk" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @GardencraftsUk</a></div>
                <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gardencrafts/200615766704712?fref=ts" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="awards">
                    <img src="images/f1.jpg">
                    <img src="images/f2.jpg">
                    <img src="images/f3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="copy">
               <p>Copyright © 2011 Gardencrafts.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
';
 ?>
```

Inside you will need to have only double quotes or escape the single quotes like so \'.

LOL. Or just simply output the html code without the echo like so:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-contact">
            <p><strong>Gardencrafts Heswall Limited</strong> <br> The Nurseries, Lower Thingwall Lane, Thingwall, <br> Wirral CH61 1AZ</p>
            <p><strong>Telephone :</strong> 0151 648 5840</p>
            <p><strong>Fax :</strong> 0151 648 5840</p>
            <p><strong>Email :</strong> gardencrafts1@gmail.com</p>
     </div>
     <div id="footer-icons">
        <div id="social-tab">
            <div id="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/GardencraftsUk" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @GardencraftsUk</a></div>
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gardencrafts/200615766704712?fref=ts" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="awards">
                <img src="images/f1.jpg">
                <img src="images/f2.jpg">
                <img src="images/f3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="copy">
           <p>Copyright © 2011 Gardencrafts.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No it will still not work, that HTML also has single quotes in it. So we need to add backslashes there

Comment: I edited the answer, to also show that there is no need for the echo here.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using php tags and echo ? do it like this, only this content(html) in that page. If you want to use any php content here just add `<?php echo $content; ?>` were ever it is required.

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-contact">
            <p><strong>Gardencrafts Heswall Limited</strong> <br> The Nurseries, Lower Thingwall Lane, Thingwall, <br> Wirral CH61 1AZ</p>
            <p><strong>Telephone :</strong> 0151 648 5840</p>
            <p><strong>Fax :</strong> 0151 648 5840</p>
            <p><strong>Email :</strong> gardencrafts1@gmail.com</p>
     </div>
     <div id="footer-icons">
        <div id="social-tab">
            <div id="twitter"><a href='https://twitter.com/GardencraftsUk' class='twitter-follow-button' data-show-count="false">Follow @GardencraftsUk</a></div>
            <div class="fb-like" data-href='https://www.facebook.com/pages/Gardencrafts/200615766704712?fref=ts' data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="awards">
                <img src="images/f1.jpg">
                <img src="images/f2.jpg">
                <img src="images/f3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="copy">
           <p>Copyright © 2011 Gardencrafts.</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use single quotes instead of double quotes in your divs just like

```
<?php 
echo "<div id='footer'></div>";
```

?>

that might also help .